# Optimize my date formatter code

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I am creating a `UIPickerView` that lets users pick a specific date and time format. I was reading that it's better to create a date formatter only once as a global function rather than to create it every time a date needs to be formatted. What I am struggling with is how to only create one date formatter for all four of the formats I want. Below is the code I have right now that works but it requires me to create four different date formatters. I am trying to find a way to only create one date formatter for all four formats.

```
let customDateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
  let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
  formatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm a zzz"
  return formatter
}()

let mediumShortDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateStyle = .medium
  formatter.timeStyle = .short
  return formatter
}()

let dateOnlyDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateStyle = .medium
  formatter.timeStyle = .none
  return formatter
}()

let timeOnlyDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateStyle = .none
  formatter.timeStyle = .short
  return formatter
}()
```

Comment: Creating a different formatter for different formats is fine

Comment: You could create one date formatter and set the date and time styles when needed but that largely negates the point of creating it just once.

Comment: Your code has one major flaw. If the user changes the device's locale while your app is running (and after these formatters have been used already), then your app will continue to format dates based on the old locale and not the new locale.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses! @rmaddy Can you suggest a solution for this issue?

Comment: Start by listening for the `NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification` notification. Then you need to rewrite your lazy properties so they can be reinitialized.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks! I will look into NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification

Comment: You can place these constants in an extension on DateFormatter as static let properties so instead of being medium DateFormatter it becomes DateFormatter.medium